# Curl not working from JetBrains IDE (Windows) for POST

Tags: java, spring, rest, curl

I am working through the Spring Guides Tutorial: Building Rest services with Spring.

I have followed along the text and entered the code in the tutorial.

I get to the part where I start the service (on local machine) and test using CURL commands.

GET works fine:

```
Curl -v localhost:8080/employees
```

returns the expected list

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Bilbo Baggins","role":"burglar"},{"id":2,"name":"Frodo Baggins","role":"thief"}]
```

However when I execute:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/employees -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"name": "Samwise Gamgee", "role": "gardener"}'
```

I get:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-11-08T20:55:49.844+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/employees"}
```

Here is the Controller Code

```
package com.mainsworth.payroll;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

 @RestController

 class EmployeeController {
     private final EmployeeRepository repository;
     EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository repository) {
         this.repository = repository;
    }

@GetMapping("/employees")
List<Employee>all() {
    return repository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping("/employees")
Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee) {
    return repository.save(newEmployee);
}

//Single item
@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
Employee one(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(()-> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));
}

@PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
Employee replaceEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee,
                         @PathVariable Long id ) {
    return repository.findById(id)
            .map(employee -> {
                employee.setName(newEmployee.getName());
                employee.setRole(newEmployee.getRole());
                return repository.save(employee);
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                newEmployee.setId(id);
                return repository.save(newEmployee);
            });

}
@DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
    repository.deleteById(id);
}

}
```

I followed Karol's and Jesper's advice.  Thanks to both for the quick response.  My new Curl is:

```
curl -X POST  localhost:8080/employees -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"name": "Samwise Gamgee","role": "gardener"}'
```

and my new response is:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-11-08T22:49:01.900+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' 
not supported","path":"/employees"}application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Samwise Gamgee,role

curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9
```

Comment: Try putting a space after the `:` in the header on the command line: `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring tutorial - CURL command to post JSON data not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775592/spring-tutorial-curl-command-to-post-json-data-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

It was happening also on my side during the tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

What was strange that on Linux OS it not happened. I double check on Linux and everything was perfectly fine.

**Solution (example):**
Instead:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/employees -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"name": "Samwise Gamgee", "role": "gardener"}'
```

Use:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/employees -H "Content-type:application/json" -d "{\"name\": \"Samwise Gamgee\", \"role\": \"gardener\"}"
```

Summarizing:
Change all ' to " and in body add \ before each "

I hope it helps!

Funfell

Answer (score 1):

Specify both `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept: application/json` request headers as your endpoint is both consuming and producing the data.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Karol. 

curl -X POST  localhost:8080/employees -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"name": "Samwise Gamgee","role": "gardener"}'

returns 

"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/employees"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Samwise Gamgee,role
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers that do work, I'd like to make people aware of a slight error in that tutorial code when it relates to Springboot 2.

I was getting a 405 after following the curl advisories described here.

I discovered that a tiny tweak to the annotation was needed:

```
@PostMapping(value="/employees",produces = "application/json")
Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee) {
return repository.save(newEmployee);
}
```

Note that the produced flag is needed to make it react properly to not be given the 405. When combined with the curl command:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"name\": \"Samwise Gamgee\", \"role\": \"gardener\"}" http://localhost:8080/employees
```