# Spring tutorial - CURL command to post JSON data not working

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, curl

I am currently working through a Spring tutorial on REST (whole tutorial is at spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/). I am pretty sure I have followed the guide accurately. I have the following code for the EmployeeController:

```
package com.example.buildingrest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeRepository repository;

    EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // Aggregate root

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    List<Employee> all() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/employees")
    Employee newEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee) {
        return repository.save(newEmployee);
    }

    // Single item

    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
    Employee one(@PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
    Employee replaceEmployee(@RequestBody Employee newEmployee, @PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
                .map(employee -> {
                    employee.setName(newEmployee.getName());
                    employee.setRole(newEmployee.getRole());
                    return repository.save(employee);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newEmployee.setId(id);
                    return repository.save(newEmployee);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

When I do a CURL command to get all employees I am successful, and when I do a CURL command to get one employee by id, I am successful. The problem is when I try to POST a new employee. I am using the following command, which comes from the tutorial:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/employees -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"name": "Samwise Gamgee", "role": "gardener"}'
```

I get the following error:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-03-20T13:28:56.244+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not
 supported","path":"/employees"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Samwise Gamgee,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: role
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9
```

As far as the unmatched close brace/bracket, I have looked at the code and the CURL command up and down and cannot find it. As far as the Unsupported Media Type, I don't understand why it is stating x-www-form-urlencoded when I have been using JSON for the whole application. And I have copied the curl command straight from the tutorial.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: -H 'Content-Type:application/json'

Comment: That did not resolve the issue

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: I'm using Windows, but I'm in the Spring Tool Suite's terminal using a Bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently the Spring tutorial has the cURL command wrong. It states the cURL command should be:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/employees -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"name": "Samwise Gamgee", "role": "gardener"}'
```

When actually, it should be:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"name\": \"Samwise Gamgee\", \"role\": \"gardener\"}" http://localhost:8080/employees
```

Comment: The tutorial of Spring are scandalous